# The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml

I go a problem about pom.xml when I run my springboot project

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I've added pluginManagement tag cover  then I builded project and it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.M5</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

    <groupId>com.telusko</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyWebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.22</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - <parent>
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-
     resources)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on your project
2. Go to "Run mode"
3. Go to "Run Configuration..."
4. When the screen opens, remove the word "pom.xml" from the "Profile:" line and click "Run".